# Balls of radius $r$ contained in finite collection of balls of radius $2r$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Say that $X$ is a compact subset of a metric space. Is it true that one can find a finite collection of balls of radius $2r$ for a fixed $r> 0$ such that any ball of radius $r$ with center in $X$ is contained in a ball in this collection?

Edit: To clarify, I want to know for any $B_r(x)$ with $x\in X$, is there a finite collection $\{B_{2r}(x_i)\}$ such that $B_r(x)$ is contained in a single $B_{2r}(x_i)$.

Comment: Is $X$ a metric space?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: I took the liberty to make a clarifying statement. Feel free to edit.

Comment: The collection of open balls of radius $r$ covers $X$. Since $X$ is compact, it has a finite subcover. Expand balls in this subcover to radius $2r$....

Comment: @G.Chiusole This edit is not quite what I wanted to say. The question is not if a ball of radius $r$ is in the union, but if there is a single ball in which it is contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of all $B(x,r)$, $x \in X$ covers $X$, which is compact, so finitely many, say $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ centres suffice to cover $X$. If now $x \in X$ for some $x_i$, $x \in B(x_i, r)$ so $d(x,x_i) < r$ and so if $d(x, y) < r$ as well, for some $y$, we have $$d(x_i,y) \le d(x_i, x) + d(x,y) < r+r=2r \text{ so } y \in B(x_i, 2r)$$

And it follows that $B(x,r) \subseteq B(x_i, 2r)$ for that $i$. As $x$ was arbitrary, the $x_i, i=1,\ldots,n$ thus are as requested.

Comment: Ah, so simple. Cool, thanks very much!

Comment: @luthien You're welcome!